# Vlookup with three columns to match in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have put two entire clusters of data on the first sheet  next to each other. I want to know which rows in the first cluster have entries in the second cluster, looking up by three column values.

For example, for a given row in the first cluster, if columns B, C, and I (first cluster) match those in columns T, U, and AA (second cluster), return 1, otherwise 0.

Comment: You know how to use `VLOOKUP` right (your deleted question tends to say so)? Why not just create a column containing a concatenate of all three columns and comparing those two?

Comment: Huh, I never thought of that. That's a really good workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((T:T=A1)*(U:U=B1)*(AA:AA=I1)),1,0)
```

it will check whether first row from first cluster have entries in the second cluster and returns `1` if yes, `0` otherwise.

To return `True`/`False`, you could slightly modify your formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((T:T=A1)*(U:U=B1)*(AA:AA=I1))>0
```